# pyodbc Module not found Azure function linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, azure-functions, pyodbc

I am deploying a python function from azure devops pipelines and I have no portal access and no ssh access to the azure function linux worker. The azure function is using a managed identity to connect to the SQL DB. I am getting the above error.

```
'''Connect to Azure SQL DB'''
credential = DefaultAzureCredential() # system-assigned identity
# Get token for Azure SQL Database and convert to UTF-16-LE for SQL Server driver
token = credential.get_token("https://database.windows.net/.default").token.encode("UTF-16-LE")
token_struct = struct.pack(f'<I{len(token)}s', len(token), token)
# Connect with the token            
SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
conn_string = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER=sql-to-dev-qasecgate.database.windows.net;DATABASE=QASecurityGatepoc"
database_conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: token_struct})            
database_cursor = database_conn.cursor()
return database_conn, database_cursor
```

[This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/249) github thread has marked the issue closed, when it clearly isn't solved. A user mentioned using `pypyodbc` instead of `pyodbc`. I tried that, however I was not able to authenticate with the Azure SQL DB using that. I couldn't find the code to do that for the mentioned scenario using `pypyodbc`.

I cannot use docker.

I remember facing the same issue when working on this earlier but at that point I had ssh access. I recall manually downloading the ODBC driver and copying the files ,probably `.ini` files? to a certain directory to get it working.
I do not remember that information now and am not sure how to get that done from a pipeline task (not YAML).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code if you want to use `pypyodbc` to connect to azure SQL DB from an Azure python function app usng Managed Identity. Couldn't find a solution to `pyodbc Module not found` Error.

```
import pypyodbc

server = '<your_server_name>.database.windows.net'
database = '<your_database_name>'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
auth = 'ActiveDirectoryMsi'

connection_string = (
    'DRIVER=' + driver + ';'
    'Server=' + server + ';'
    'Database=' + database + ';'
    'Authentication=' + auth + ';'
)

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)

print("Connected")
```